# Included jQuery not works under production mode raise `is not a function` error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I put the `jquery.placeholder.js` under `assets/javascripts` folder

then apply the function in my coffeescript file and works fine.

```
$(document).ready ->
  $('input, textarea').placeholder();
```

However, When I run in production mode by `RAILS_ENV=production rails s`

Raise `not a function error` on Firebug console
[image]

I put other related files on gist

https://gist.github.com/poc7667/7576566

Answer (score 0):

Uncomment line : 50 in config/enviroments/production.rb and add `jquery.placeholder.js` in it to precompile it

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( jquery.placeholder.js )
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But it didn't work.After I uncommented the code  you mention. Then `rake assets:clean` `RAILS_ENV=production rails s`

Comment: After adding this line, you have to precompile your assets using the command `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile` then start your server & try..